# SQL Server query throws Deadlock Exception on rs.next

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

We run a SELECT statement using preparedStatement.executeQuery on a SQL Server database. The query fails with a deadlock exception which is expected. The problem here is, the exception is not thrown on the executeQuery but thrown while we are doing rs.next() ie., while reading the result set. Is there any reason for this behaviour? What can we do to make it throw the exception on executeQuery?

Driver jar - sqljdbc4 - 4.0.2206.100

Java version - 1.8

Query Executed: `SELECT Col1 from Table1 where Col2 = ?`

Error trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 66) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:6357)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1798)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1049)
```

Comment: The thing is, you Java code may not have actually touched the result set until you call `ResultSet#next()`.  But, this aside, why do you expect _any_ deadlock to be happening here?  Your question is a bit like asking why did my car breakdown 5 minutes after hitting a nail, rather than immediately.

Comment: We are handling deadlock scenario by retries. We do a try-catch on the execute and get the exception and then retry if its a deadlock. It works fine for executeUpdate. But executeQuery does not throw the exception, it appears to have executed without issue, then when we proceed to read the result set it says there is a deadlock. We want to detect the deadlock while executing the query only and throw exception, not wait for us until we read the result set

Comment: SQL Server will only hit a deadlock when it actually tries to read a row...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Do you know if there is a specific reason to do so? Ideally I would be expecting a deadlock error while executing the query and not while trying to iterate a result set. I might choose not to iterate the result set or do anything with that. In that case, how would I know that a deadlock had occurred?

Comment: Because most databases will only read rows when they are actually required (that is on `next()` or when `next()` triggers fetch of a batch of rows), in addition, SQL Server reports errors per row. So the error will only be thrown when you attempt to read the row that triggered the error from the result set.